# "Double-Length pseudolanguage" Option in Xcode 8+?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Is it available in interface builder still? I know I can do it in the simulator by editing a scheme but wondering if it's possible to do in Xcode interface builder still?

This is a picture of what I am looking for:

[image: This is a picture of what I am looking for, thanks.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is. go to your storyboard, select the assistant editor. then in the top bar of the right pane choose "preview". and finally in the bottom bar you choose the double-length pseudolanguage.